# how to connect to jasperserver repository database

Tags: jasperserver

I need to import some pdf files into jasper server, for this i need to access JICONTENTRESOURCE table of repository database.

But I could not find a way to locate my repository's database (default POSTGRESQL). Can any one explain how to connect to jasperserver repository database using SQL developer/ or any other tool. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Default repository DB name is 'jasperserver'. Credentials depend on what you specified during installation (default_master.properties file in case WAR file was used).

Although, you should upload resources by interacting with the application. You could use web UI (View/Repository then right-click on folder and select Add resource/File/Content Resource) or REST API web services to design a script/programm to automate the process.

Comment: Thank you, i am now able to connect to jasperserver database now, also do u have any example or sample or page link to check as reference which expalians the REST webservices for uploading, can you please share here, thanks in advance

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-rest-api-reference/v630/working-file-resources#Uploading_File_Resources

Comment: i tried this link but still not able to achieve it :'(